# Image animation move and scale together

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have 4 image view I want to move image 1 to position of image 2 with move and scale animation.
[[image: How it looks like]

What I have tried for scaling

```
ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img1, "scaleX", (float) img2.getWidth());
    ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img1, "scaleY", (float) img2.getHeight());
    scaleX.setDuration(2000);
    scaleY.setDuration(2000);
    AnimatorSet scale = new AnimatorSet();
    scale.play(scaleX).with(scaleY);
    scale.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a lot of code with [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) plus you can combine multiple animations in one line :

```
img1.animate()
    .scaleX(toX)
    .scaleY(toY)
    .translationX(toX)
    .translationY(toY)
    .setDuration(2000);
```

There are also methods :

```
.scaleXBy(byX)
.translationYBy(byY)
```

that scale/translate the methods **BY** the given value

For the translation you have to keep in mind that  :

```
img2.getX();
img2.getY();
```

only gives you the coordinates of the upper left corner of the view img2 .

You probably want to animate to the center of img2 which would be

```
img2.getX() / 2;
img2.getY() / 2;
```

All combined something like this should work :

```
img1.animate()
    .scaleX(...)
    .scaleY(...)
    .translationX(img2.getX() / 2)
    .translationY(img2.getY() / 2)
    .setDuration(2000);
```

EDIT : I found this page on the developer training site you can check out :

[Zooming a view](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But it's not working. I just checked the documents - scale mean "Sets the amount that the view is scaled in x around the pivot point, as a proportion of the view's unscaled width. A value of 1 means that no scaling is applied."

Comment: well then all you need is other values for scaleX() and scaleY() , for example scaleX(2) scales to two times the original size.

Comment: But how can I give value of other imageview hight and width.